# How can I insert formula with relative cell references using ExcelDNA?

Tags: c#, excel, excel-dna

I am looking to write a formula such as "=SUM(A1, B1)" to a cell using ExcelDNA.

I am currently able to output it with absolute references in the form "=SUM(R1C1, R1C2)" which results in the formula being output as "=SUM($A$1,$B$1)":

```
XlCall.Excel(XlCall.xlcFormula, "=SUM(R1C1,R1C2)");
```

When I try this call using relative references:

```
XlCall.Excel(XlCall.xlcFormula, "=SUM(A1,B1)");
```

Excel reports a problem was found with the formula when it is called.

Is it possible to have this output as a relative reference "=SUM(A1, B1)"?

Comment: try with square brackets like one can do in VBA. Possibly something like this will work: `"=sum(r[1]c[1]:r[1]C[2]"` or try with minus figures inside brackets like: `"=sum(r[-1]c[-1]:r[-1]C[-2]"` depending where you is the cell you put the formula in relation to `A1:B1`.

Comment: You can also convert a formula from A1-style to RC-style using XlCall.Excel(XlCall.xlfFormulaConvert, "=SUM(A1, B1)", true, false) and passing the result to xlcFormula.